# How to use Parallel.ForEach to read cells data from excel file

Tags: c#

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to read excel file as following:

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = sheet.UsedRange;


        var rangeValues = range.Value;
        List<string> EmailList = new List<string)();


          foreach (String str in rangeValues)
        {
            //addDataToList(EmailList, str); // add value to List<String>
            EmailList.Add(str);
        }
```

range.Value is dynamic so the question is how to use Parallel to read cells data from excel file? with something like:

```
        //    Parallel.ForEach(rangeValues, (str) => { addEmailToList(EmailList, str); });
```

Comment: Are the interop libraries thread safe ? and if they are, does it dispatch to a single thread....

Comment: @TheGeneral not sure about that, I just want to accelarate reading data from excel

Comment: When you tried the Parallel.ForEach. what happened ?

Comment: `// add value to List<String>` `List.Add` is not thread-safe.

Comment: @mjwills the above code is working, my question is how to read data from excel in parallel, then save it in any data structure, do have a solution for that? or any suggestions?

Comment: I can certainly give suggestions, once you provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills It is up there, the code is working!!!, I want to change the way I am reading the data.

Comment: When I try and run the code it complains about `addDataToList` not being defined. It doesn't _feel_ like a [mcve].

Comment: Your question, as is, is basically "please make this code (that you can't see, and I won't show you) thread-safe". That is, shall we say, a tricky task.

Comment: @mjwills by the way, List.Add is currently works in main thread, changing reading method to make it works in parallel requires change data structure, if have an idea, or anything help else critique please point to it simply, I am not request you to write code, I will write it.

Answer (score 2):

See [Threading support in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/threading-support-in-office?view=vs-2019)

> The Office object model is not thread safe, but it is possible to work with multiple threads in an Office solution. Office applications are Component Object Model (COM) servers. COM allows clients to call COM servers on arbitrary threads. For COM servers that are not thread safe, COM provides a mechanism to serialize concurrent calls so that only one logical thread executes on the server at any time. This mechanism is known as the single-threaded apartment (STA) model. Because calls are serialized, callers might be blocked for periods of time while the server is busy or is handling other calls on a background thread.

I.e. even if you managed to read cells in parallel, at best all except one thread would block, and at worst your application would break.

If performance is a concern I would suggest finding another way to read values. There should be other libraries that may do this faster.